# Relation of SPT phases with different boundary conditions

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

Using the definition that two SPT phases are distinct if they can't be connected by a symmetric finite depth local unitary, how does one relate systems with different boundary conditions?

For example, the ground state of the Majorana chain with periodic/antiperiodic boundary conditions have different fermion parities. Why do we consider them the same phase if one must break fermion parity to connect them?